# When do i use row vectors over column vectors when showing the basis of null space of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-5&4&-2&2\\1&-6&5&-3&2\\-2&11&-8&5&-2 \end{bmatrix} $$
and define a linear transformation, $T: \mathbb{R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}^3 \quad \text{by} \quad T(x) = Ax \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^5 $

for question 2(a) I row reduced the given matrix and found that there were 3 linearly independent rows and columns. My question is, which one should i give to show the basis? For columns, I have that the basis of kernal(T) is {[1,1,0], [-5,1,1], [4,-1,0]} Is this correct?

Comment: "basis of $T$" makes no sense: linear transformations do not have bases, vector spaces do. What exactly are you trying to find a basis of? If it's the null space of $T$ as your title suggests, you should review what this means since the null space of $T$ will not consist of vectors in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: basis of the kernal of T. Sorry i used to have a picture but i guess a mod edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Row reduce.

**Step 2** Take the variables corresponding to columns without pivots and gives them the value zero to all of them except to one to which you give the value $1$. For each choice of what variable got the value $1$ apply back substitution to compute the values for the variables corresponding to the columns that do have pivots. This gives you a vector of solutions for each choice of the variable that gets the value $1$. These vectors form a basis of the kernel.

Comment: so i could just set x4 and x5 to be free variables (since x1,x2,and x3 are defined) and basically solve as if i'm solving for the null space of the matrix?

Comment: I don't know what variables are going to have pivots or not. I haven't computed the echelon form.

Comment: are the operations similar to solving for the null space of a matrix?